# How to enable SSL on domain without subdomain?

Tags: ssl, dns

I have a rails app and am using Heroku. I have SSL enabled.

`https://www.mywebsite.example` works just fine.

However, `https://mywebsite.example` does not work. What is the best approach to address this? Should I redirect `https://mywebsite.example` to the domain with ‘www’ and if so will the site still be secure.

Or should I enable SSL for `https://mywebsite.example` as well?

In the domain settings, I have:

```
Name: www
Type: CNAME
Data: blahblahblah.herokudns.com
```

Comment: "does not work" is not valid troubleshootingl you should instead specify exactly what you test, what results you get, and what you expected instead. Have a look at [mcve] for further guidance. Besides you are offtopic here.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would redirect www to the 'naked' domain and ensure as you have that SSL is installed on the 'naked' domain correctly.

You are then only maintaining a single instance of your site/app, rather than what Google and others will see as two individual 'sites'. (www and naked).

Comment: How should I go about doing this in the DNS settings (I'm using Google Domains)?

Comment: I am not personally familiar with Google Domains - however a quick google on what I have suggested found this article which might fix your issue: https://www.tachyonstemplates.com/2018/google-domains-forward-root/

This article presumes you want domain.com to forward to www.domain.dom ('naked' to www).